# GTK compiling works with gcc but not with g++. g++ does not recognize -rdynamic command

Tags: c++, user-interface, gcc, g++, gtk

This is my code for both main.c and main.cpp

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>



void quitButtonClicked(__attribute__((unused)) GtkWidget *widget,
                __attribute__((unused)) gpointer   data)
{
        g_print("Quit Clicked\n");
        gtk_main_quit();
}


// Handle the user trying to close the window
gboolean windowDelete(__attribute__((unused)) GtkWidget *widget,
                __attribute__((unused)) GdkEvent  *event,
                __attribute__((unused)) gpointer   data)
{
        g_print("%s called.\n",__FUNCTION__);
        return FALSE;    // Returning TRUE stops the window being deleted.
        // Returning FALSE allows deletion.
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
        GtkWidget *window;
        GtkBuilder *builder = NULL;

        gtk_init (&argc , &argv);

        builder = gtk_builder_new();

        if(gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder,"window_main.glade" , NULL) == 0)
        {
                printf("gtk_builder_add_from_file FAILED\n");
                return(0);
        }
        window  = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder,"window1"));


        gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder,NULL);

        gtk_widget_show_all (window);
        gtk_main ();
        return 0;
}
```

When compiling with
gcc -o hello_world $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) -rdynamic main.c

everything works out perefectly.

But running this doesnt work.
g++ -o hello_world $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0) -rdynamic main.cpp

I get this warning.

(hello_world:40684): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:32:33.179: Could not find signal handler 'windowDelete'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

What does I do to modify my g++ compiling to ensure this works as expected? I want to run C++ code later not C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to surround the functions with

```
 extern "C" {
 }
```

Otherwise the function/symbol names are C++ mangeled, which GTK cannot look up.